# database query not matching second condition

Tags: php, mysql, database

Seems like a stupid thing to get stuck on right now but I can't get a second condition to match my database column.  When I do it like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id='$link'"
```

I get all the comments related to the article name.  But when I add a second condition, I get nothing:

```
"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id='$link' AND show=1"
```

I tried doing show='1' also and that didn't work.  The last column in my database is an INT and default value is as defined:1.  How can I get my multi conditional query to work?  Thanks...

Comment: What is `$link` equal to? What error message did you receive?

Comment: Is there actual data matching both conditions? Doesn't matter if you set a default value, you might have inserted a row with that value as null or something else...

Comment: What is the value of `show` for rows returned from the first query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error isn't in just condition. `SHOW` is in list of MySQL [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). So escape it:

```
SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id='$link' AND `show`=1
```

-or else, don't use reserved words for naming columns. Of course, be sure that rows with `show=1` exist in table.

Comment: +1, I've learnt it to be good practice to escape all columns too, from a readability standpoint.

Comment: That was the problem...I changed the column name from show to display and now it works...when will I learn!!!  Keep forgetting about the reserved words

Answer (score 3):

`show` is a keyword in mysql. The query must be failing. Use `show` with backticks like this `show`

Answer (score 1):

`show` is mysql [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), so you need wrap it with backtick `` `show` ``

```
"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE article_id='$link' AND `show`=1"
```